# bulleted list with different indentation

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Can I make bulleted lists on my site that use <ul> and <li> tags have a different indentation distances?

- Element One
- Element Two
  and even this line  
  which is not in an <li> tag are indented

List elements without the <ul> tags are

not indented

I would like to indent some elements, but the default distance is too much and the sans-indent is too little.

Comment: The "sans-indent" you speak of isn't even valid HTML anyway (and neither is text directly within a `<ul>` tag).

Comment: Have you tried playing with the padding/margin properties in the style tag? `<ul style="margin:0px;padding:5px;">`

Comment: @BoltClock: yup.  validator.w3 wanted to stab me; I was surprised it worked at all (saw it on some random website whilst naively googling my own question first)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
<ul style="padding-left:20px">
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
</ul>
```

I think the default indentation is `40px`, this halves it.

Comment: I believe the `</li>` is unnecessary. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html

Comment: @tlyim: That's right, you can skip it. I generally wouldn't though, it can confuse other people that read your code. Here's a more recent link with more details about what you can omit: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/syntax.html#optional-tags

Answer (score 4):

```
li {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
ul li{ 
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

A slightly cleaner way to adjust both of the indentations. Margin and padding differ, so use whichever suits you best.

Comment: in this case is it preferable to change margin-left instead of padding-left?

Comment: It seems as though changing the margin can only indent it farther, as the padding is really the in-between-elements-level distance